# How do I approach this using a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm still in the learning android development process so this may be a simple concept.

**What I'm trying to achieve.**

1. MainActivity has a RecyclerView with a staggered grid layout of images pulled from internet.
2. Images can be expanded with touch and have the option to save or share.

**What I have now.**

1. I have a working recyclerView with dummy text and image for testing purpose.

Biggest obstacle...

I know I have to obtain an API key from a website with images I want displayed in the recyclerView, but I cannot find a website that provides the kind of images I want with an API key as well. Could I create a web database of the images I want and then implement them into my app with some API key? Is this possible, if so how would I do this?

Comment: You'll need to learn about [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/), php and SQL. Search on google you'll find a lot of tutorials and explanations

Answer (score 0):

The information is not enough. Do you want to use some backend API or some free web resource like wordpress? 
In the first case you shoul create a backend part (API) on your server to have opportunities to get content from it. 
In the second you can post your content in free web sites. If it have not some API for net requests you can parse HTML page code to get content and download it via Picasso, UniversalImageLoader, Volley etc. or implement your oun downloader. I hope it is helpful for you.